# Magento2 > Safely disable Add-To-Cart buttons

Tags: cart, product-list

**EDIT: This post apply to Magento 2.x**

I would like to remove all add-to-cart button instances from my website. 
I know I could do it from various way (removing that block with xml, removing from phtml...), while this is not an issue for me, I would like to know if there is a really safe way to do it in case I would have forgot to remove it from some place or the other. I want to completely remove the checkout and cart feature but wishlist and compare must stay.

Some specs:

1. Compare and wishlists are still enabled
2. Prices are listed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by just changing the settings of the products.

For instance, set up a product to not be "saleable", or to have no stock and disable "out of stock" messages site-wide. Then configure the inventory module to still show products out of stock in their categories.

Comment: Phil this  is a silly tricky solution:)

Comment: Not every solution requires code, Amit.

Comment: Ha ha..your right